# Exchange2010 MAPI Limit

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have Exchange2010 client is outlook2010. We have a user who has about 7 additional mailboxes due to her role. She is hitting the MAPI limit of 500 connections for "ObjectFolder"

Event log 9646 is generated.

I have tried to apply the fix of creating a registry key called "MaxObjsPerMapiSession" as per the Microsoft KB in `\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem`. I have restarted the info store but we are stil seeing Event 9646 errors for this user.

I need to up the limit for this user (or globally) I cannot remove her additional mailboxes. Any suggestions.

Comment: Just to clarify what you did, after creating the MaxObjsPerMapiSession, did you also create a new click DWORD Value and setting the value name "objtFolder" with the actual value anything above 500? (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676486%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx - some additional notes)

Comment: Yes sorry. I Created the Dword and set it to 1000,

Comment: Curious... Do the additional mailboxes show up in Outlook Web Access?

Comment: @ewwhite No they do not. As OWA cannot see additional mailboxes unless you use the "Select Mailbox Feature"

Comment: Oh, I was thinking you were enabling "full mailbox access" via the Exchange management console. That will place the other mailboxes in the user's left pane, even on OWA.

Comment: @ewwhite i think you have mis-read the quesion. The problem is with MAPI limits not with Mailbox acesss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Soloution as in my Quesion as to reg key \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem. But this needed a full reboot of the server not just a restart of the Info stor as per the MS artical.